# How to setToRecipients MFMailComposerViewController in Xcode6

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I am Using Xcode 6.

I am using MFMailComposerViewController to send emails within the app.

I am able to call MFMailComposerViewController,which provides the standard Interface to send emails.

I am able to set the subject as well.

But I am not able to set the Recipients.

Here is my code.

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

   mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
   [mailComposer setSubject:@"PSA Mobile CRM"];
   NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"abc@mass.uk.net"];
   [mailComposer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

   mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
   [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];  
}

else {       
   NSLog(@"This device cannot send email");   
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult (MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {  
   switch (result) {

      case MFMailComposeResultSent:          
      NSLog(@"You sent the email.");     
      break;

      case MFMailComposeResultSaved:     
      NSLog(@"You saved a draft of this email");     
      break;

      case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:    
      NSLog(@"You cancelled sending this email.");     
      break;

      case MFMailComposeResultFailed:    
      NSLog(@"Mail failed:  An error occurred when trying to compose this email");     
      break;

      default:     
      NSLog(@"An error occurred when trying to compose this email");  
      break;
  }

 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL]; }
```

I am able to send the email.
But I am not able to set the `setToRecipients` method.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: Are you testing on simulator ?

Comment: yes.........but its working on real device now.
that means in ios8 it doesn't work on simulator.

Comment: Yes on simulator it works buggy.. Better to test on device.